# Модели ActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, yii, mysql

Добрый день!
Разбираюсь с моделями `CActiveRecord`.
На сколько я понял, любая модель `CActiveRecord` - это обертка над таблицей в базе. Метод `findAll()` выполняет запрос типа:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` `t`
```

Но, на практике обычно нужны более сложные запросы, в которых прописаны связи с другими таблицами. Например:

```
SELECT p.*, c.title
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id_cat = p.id_cat
```

Вопрос в том, возможно ли такие связи прописывать в модели, чтобы при вызове `findAll()` они автоматически строили сложный SQL-запрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Связи прописываются в методе public function relations(). Далее делаем такой вызов

```
$posts=Post::model()->with('author','categories')->findAll();
```

Где 'author','categories' - названия связей. Вообще читаем тут [реляционные отношения в CActiveRecords](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.arr).